# How to get Code Coverage working on a VS 2010 project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unity-container

When I turn on Code Coverage in my test settings, on a project that references the Unity DI container I get the following error:

> Cannot initialize the ASP.NET project
>   '{Project Name}'.

The event log specifies the following reason:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.

How do I get around this issue?

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on a Windows 7 X64 machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test run errors with MSTest in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761587/test-run-errors-with-mstest-in-vs2010)

Comment: I see that now. Though the answer came to this question. An way of combining the answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*How do I get around this issue?*

A shot in the dark without knowing the root cause:
Have you tried using the strong name utility to skip verification of the offending assembly(s)?

```
sn -Vr <assembly>
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I've had same problem and
sn -Vr "Microsoft.Practices.Unity,31bf3856ad364e35"
sn -Vr "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation,31bf3856ad364e35"
sn -Vr "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration,31bf3856ad364e35"

did the trick! Very cool.

Comment: Is `sn` a command line utility that has to be run from cmd, or could it be run from within VS? I'm unable to run it in either. How do I use it?

Comment: Tomas, I run it from the VS command line which I believe just refers to sn.exe as installed in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I've had [the exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761587/test-run-errors-with-mstest-in-vs2010) (although with Ninject) - see the second error in my question.

The proposed solution (which I haven't had time to verify yet) is to re-build the non-working assembly with signing turned off.

This assumes, of course, that you have the source code available. I had to build Ninject against .NET 4 myself (there was no released version for .NET 4 when I started the project), which is why I ended up in this situation in the first place.

Comment: :) Hello, Tomas. Looks like sn -Vr can fix problems, and there is no need to compile code without key.