# Unit Test/Code Coverage Warning & Error VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, code-coverage

I have a sample test project given to developers on my project team to learn how to use automated tests.  When I run the set of unit tests that I have, they all pass but I receive the following Warning and Error:

> > Warning: conflict during test run deployment: deployment item '[...]\WebAppMvc4.dll' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container '[...]\webappmvc4.tests.dll' cannot be deployed to 'WebAppMvc4.dll' because otherwise the file '[...]\WebAppMvc4.dll' would overwrite deployment item '[...]\WebAppMvc4.dll' directly or indirectly referenced by '[...]\webappmvc4.tests.dll'
> >
> > Error:  Cannot initialize the ASP.NET project 'WebAppMvc4'.
> >     Exception was thrown: The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:12903/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

This is very similar to the problem found here:  [Test run errors with MSTest in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761587/test-run-errors-with-mstest-in-vs2010)

However, the resolution to this problem had to do with turning off the Sign The Assembly checkbox in the project properties.  Signing is not turned on for this project, and I have not been able to determine the reason for the Warning/Error.

Here is the information from Event Viewer for the Warning:

> > Event code: 3008 
> >     Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
> >     Event time: 6/27/2012 9:40:51 AM 
> >     Event time (UTC): 6/27/2012 2:40:51 PM 
> >     Event ID: a9b4d9d93e334acbbde6184527b4cd81 
> >     Event sequence: 1 
> >     Event occurrence: 1 
> >     Event detail code: 0
> >
> > Process information: 
> >         Process ID: 4128 
> >         Process name: WebDev.WebServer40.EXE
> >
> > Exception information: 
> >         Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
> >         Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
> >        at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
> >        at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
> >        at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
> >        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
> >        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
> >        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
> >        at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
> >
> > Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
> >
> > Request information: 
> >         Request URL:

```
http://localhost:12903/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd
```

And here is the info for the Error:

> > (QTAgent32.exe, PID 9392, Thread 7) CoveragePlugIn.InitAspNet threw in calling WorkerProcessIdentity or WorkerProcessImpersonatedIdentity for 'WebAppMvc4':
> >
> > Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelperException: The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed.
> >
> > Requesting 'http://localhost:12903/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> >
> > at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.BaseHelper.GetWorkerProcessInfo()
> >        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.BaseHelper.GetWorkerProcessInfo()
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodeCoverage.CoveragePlugIn.InitAspNet(TestRun testRun)